# Калькулятор вклада с учетом капитализации процентов

Tags: javascript

Еесть задача сделать калькулятор вкладов. В калькуляторе 2 поля: `input` и `select`. `input` - под сумму, `select` - выбор срока вклада.

Прошу обратить внимание на формулу подсчёта вклада: `(sum * 0.135 / 365 * 91).toFixed(2)` - по-русски это так: (`сумма * на процент / кол-во дней в году *  срок вклада в днях)`. Такой вклад называется "с капитализацией", вклад длится 365 дней.

Например, есть вклад 10 000 на 12 месяцев. Обычный вклад посчитается так: `(sum * 0.135 / 365 * 365).toFixed(2)`, а вот с капитализацией должен так:

```
var x = (sum * 0.135 / 365 * 31).toFixed(2) //первый месяц 
var z = ((x + sum) * 0.135 / 365 * 31).toFixed(2) //второй месяц
var q = ((z + sum) * 0.135 / 365 * 31).toFixed(2) //третий месяц
```

То есть получается, что каждый последующий месяц проценты начисляются на сумму + процент с предыдущего месяца.

Я пытаюсь такой вклад сделать через цикл `for`:

```
else if ( days == 12 ) { // селект равен 12 то тогда
    var resvkl1 = (sum * 0.135 / 365 * 91).toFixed(2); //считаем сумму первого вклада
    var resvkl2 = (sum * 0.125 / 365 * 91).toFixed(2); //считаем сумму второго вклада
    var resvkl3 = 0; //третий вклад
    var c;
    for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) { //проходим по 12 месяцам
        if (i % 2 == 0) { //отделяем чет и нечет, т.к. в месяце 30 или 31 день
            resvkl3 = resvkl3 + sum * 0.13 / 365 * 30;
            console.log(resvkl3 + ' тут ' +i);
        }
        else {
            resvkl3 = resvkl3 + sum * 0.13 / 365 * 31;
            console.log(resvkl3);
        }
    }
    conc.innerHTML = thead + tvkl1 + resvkl1 + tvklc + tvkl2 + resvkl2 + tvklc + tvkl3 + resvkl3 + tvklc + tablec; 
}
```

Почему проценты не считаются с учётом предыдущего месяца, хотя если в цикл вставить, например:

```
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        //resvkl3 = resvkl3 + sum * 0.11 / 365 * 91;
        resvkl3 = resvkl3 + sum + 2;
        console.log(resvkl3 + ' тут ' +i);
    }
    else {
        resvkl3 = resvkl3  + sum + 3;
        console.log(resvkl3);
    }
}
```

то идёт сложение с учётом предыдущей переменной?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < days; i++) { //проходим по 12 месяцам` вы уверены что days это месяцы?

Comment: `//отделяем чет и нечет, т.к. в месяце 30 или 31 день` про Февраль не забыли?

Comment: @KromStern да, это месяцы, ну просто сначало думал в днях сделать, но потом передумал, а искать везде переменную не охото, про февраль - да ну его, не большая погрешность допустима

Comment: Вам не кажется, что при капитализации вот тут (`resvkl3 = resvkl3 + sum * 0.13 / 365 * 30;`) сумма должна увеличиваться?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов А почему вы не хотите воспользоваться [формулой для расчёта сложных процентов](http://bankirsha.com/formula-calculate-of-interest-on-deposit.html)?

Comment: @KromStern должна, так вроде увеличивается..

Comment: `resvkl3` увеличивается, а сумма `sum` с которой вы считаете процент - нет.

Comment: *2 дня туда, 2 дня сюда, никто не заметит* - Не хотел бы я иметь дело с банком, который у вас такую работу примет.

Comment: @KromStern этот калькулятор для ознакомления, "resvkl3 увеличивается, а сумма sum" - так я же их складываю, и она должна увеличваться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы складываете 12 раз по 1/12 от процентов за год, без капитализации. А с капитализацией будет как вы сами выше и писали должно быть:

```
resvkl3 = resvkl3 + (sum + resvkl3) * 0.13 / 365 * 30;
```

То есть в каждой итерации сумма с которой считается процент должна становится больше на размер уже начисленных процентов.

Comment: заработало, спасибо!

Comment: И все же поправьте Февраль (согласно ТЗ вашего заказчика, такие вещи там должны быть оговорены) или уберите `i % 2 == 0` и замените `/ 365 * 30` на `/ 12` - так ошибка будет меньше, а логика цельнее.

Comment: "/ 365 * 30 на / 12" не могу - это по тз, а вот учитывать февраль - предлогал (я вообще предлагал сделать всплывающий календарь с выбором даты и тд), но заказчик сказал что не надо усложнять

Comment: Чудной у вас заказчик, упрощать для более корректного результата не хочет, усложнять для более точного тоже ) Но в одном есть плюс, что есть ТЗ - делайте по нему.

Comment: Банки считают интервалами по ровно 30 дней.